How do get the swap path for multi pool swaps uniswap v3
I want to be able to make dynamic multi pools swaps in my smart contract. My plan is to use the exactInput function found here: https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/main/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol#L26
However I can't figure out how I can create the path variable. I would think uniswap has a utility somewhere to interact with the Auto Router but I can't seem to find it
I'm pretty sure the Auto Router is exposed here, but I can't figure out where its deployed: https://github.com/Uniswap/routing-api

The auto routing part is done offchain. So you can use the API to get the path and pass it to your contract

Thats what im trying to figure out. Which API? I cant seem to find any documentation about how to get the swap path

Maybe here https://docs.uniswap.org/sdk/v3/guides/swaps/routing

Thanks this led me to the correct answer!

I figured it out. You can get the path if you copy the following code example
https://github.com/Uniswap/examples/blob/main/v3-sdk/routing/src/libs/routing.ts#L40
The example is broken if you use the latest versions of the uniswap sdks libraries. So make sure you are using the same version as the example
    "@uniswap/sdk-core": "^3.1.0",
    "@uniswap/smart-order-router": "^3.0.6",
    "@uniswap/v3-sdk": "^3.9.0",

